# Preposition Usage; "My interest in ~", "My interest about ~" or "My interest to ~"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-choice

I wonder which one of these is the best sentence.

Or, if they make different meaning in sentence, please explain it to me !

```
1. My interest in human right in North Korea has started from CNN documentary.
2. My interest about human right in North Korea has started from CNN documentary.
3. My interest to human right in North Korea has started from CNN documentary.
```

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is **in**. People have an interest *in* things. See the attached graph. It includes both the simple present (interest) and simple past (interested) forms. The number of uses of *interest(ed) about* things is so low that it is represented by just a line straight across the bottom of the graph. I did not include *interest to* because in your sentence that is not grammatical.

Examples include:

1 I am interested *in* human rights.

2 My interest in human rights began with...

3 He is interested *in* that woman...

[image]

If you want to use *about*, a common word used with it is *curious* or *curiosity*.

Examples include:

1 I am curious *about* human rights.

2 My curiosity *about* human rights began with...

3 He is curious *about* that woman...

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation with examples. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found it helpful.